# Has anyone gotten SQL Compant 4 working on a Rackspace Cloud Site?

Tags: sql-server-ce, rackspace-cloud

I've been trying to deploy a lightweight site on a Rackspace Cloud Site (not a Cloud Server) that uses SQL CE 4 to store simple contact-form submissions. I keep getting the `Required permissions cannot be acquired` error whenever I try to access the database.

I'm not sure what I can do (if anything) to resolve it since I don't have access to IIS or the machine-level config in this server model. As I unerstand it, SQL CE 4 is supposed to work in medium trust under ASP.NET 3.5, but I

Here's the error dump:

> Required permissions cannot be acquired. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Required
>   permissions cannot be acquired.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +7606467
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean
>   checkExecutionPermission) +57
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]    System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +43
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +127
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +142    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
>   +54    System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +600
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories) +125
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories() +265
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +320
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>   +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8901019
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact only works with Medium Trust out of the box with ASP.NET 4.0, not with 3.5 SP1. The machine.config needs to be modified to work with 3.5 SP1 and medium trust - more info in my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/10/sql-server-compact-40-under-aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks, Eric, that looks like what I needed. I'll give it a whirl.